# Ctrl+right in Visual Studio Code stops working randomly

Tags: visual-studio-code

The expected behavior is that when pressed, the cursor jumps to the end of the word it's on.
From time to time, the combination will do absolutely nothing when pressed.

I tried checking if I have any shortcut set to this combination but there's none.
Anybody get this too? It doesn't happen too often, but when it happens once, it will not work again until I restart the computer.

Comment: A full computer restart - not just a restart of vscode?

Comment: Yeah... Unfortunately only a full on, literal, computer restart seems to fix the problem. At least until it comes back again in a completely random amount of time.

Comment: And this affects only vscode and no other program on your computer?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Very weird. Feels like some conflict between shortcuts or something, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: So closing vscode and opening it again doesn't fix it?

Comment: No it doesn't. As stated before, the only work around I've found (and I did try almost everything under my belt before getting to this solution of sorts) is to restart the computer.

Comment: Can't reproduce; sorry.